Italics and bold missing in comments for Firefox 53/54?
I don't get any italized or bold text at all anymore, neither in text of a post nor in the comments.
What goes wrong on my Firefox 53.0.3 (32-bit) (strikethrough works) Firefox 54.0 (64 bit) on Windows 10?
What has changed on crypto.stackexchange.com in the style sheets? This must have been a recent change!
Already tried remedies:

hiding Open Sans font on my Windows machine (Google / Ascender Open Sans version 1.10, set of 10 fonts);
installing a brand new version of Firefox (FF Portable 54.0);
installing the 64 bit version instead of the 32 bit version (used for compatability reasons);
restarting / refreshing etc;
changed screen DPI (125% -> 100%);
reset my Windows 10 font settings;
unhide fonts not required by locale settings.

Info from the developer view:
font-family: "Open Sans","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
font-feature-settings: normal;
font-kerning: auto;
font-language-override: normal;
font-size: 13px;
font-size-adjust: none;
font-stretch: normal;
font-style: italic;
font-synthesis: weight style;
font-variant: normal;
font-variant-alternates: normal;
font-variant-caps: normal;
font-variant-east-asian: normal;
font-variant-ligatures: normal;
font-variant-numeric: normal;
font-variant-position: normal;
font-weight: 400;

Possible issues (i.e. further troubleshooting):

the italics font cannot be downloaded by FF and it reverts to the regular font (??).


It works like a charm in my Chrome browser. Note that my screen size is 2560 by 1440, not a hugely common resolution.
Bold and italics still work on any other StackOverflow site. It must be a font issue.

It doesn't work here anymore either. This text should be bold.

Your comment is bold for me. On Android with Chrome.

Works for me using Firefox 53.0.3 (32-bit) on Windows 7.

Works for me in Firefox 54.0 (32-bit) on Windows 10. @CodesInChaos and Maarten you may want to update your Firefox version :P I also just confirmed it's working for me on v 1.0.94 of the SE app on stock Android 6.0 (should be the same renderer as Mike used). I also just tested on the main Crypto.SE and it worked for me there as well (with FF at least, didn't test Android).

Echo what @SEJPM wrote. Works for me as usual too. (my current "on the road" specs: Xubuntu 17.04 zesty, Firefox 54)

I confirm it works fine with all of the fonts you quoted on FF 54.0 running on Linux. You may try setting up a new user to see if it work with a "cleaner state" environment, but this seems related to your device. Thanks for the  keyword, I wasn't aware it was supported.

Bold doesn't work for question body as well on Google Chrome Version 64.0.3282.186 (Official Build) (64-bit) (Windows)
